# Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, authlogic

Using authlogic gem to validate user log in in the browser but getting "Your account in not active error" I have tried all the solutions I could find over the web but none of them seem to work.

Calling the command `Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(controller)` before creating a session solves the problem at least in `irb`.

Doing the same in the `UserSessionsController` dosent get you anywhere. I have tried calling the `before_action :activate_authlogic` in the `UserSessionsController` while the definition for the said function was placed in `application_controller.rb`

Here is my code

#### user_sessions_controller.rb

```
class   UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params.to_h)
    if @user_session.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:login, :password, :remember_me)
  end

end
```

#### user_session.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

  private
    def current_user_session
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
    end

    # def activate_authlogic
    #   Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
    # end
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_profile

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.crypto_provider = ::Authlogic::CryptoProviders::SCrypt
  end

  validates :email,
    format: {
      with: /@/,
      message: "should look like an email address."
    },
    length: { maximum: 100 },
    uniqueness: {
      case_sensitive: false,
      if: :will_save_change_to_email?
    }

  validates :login,
    format: {
      with: /\A[a-z0-9]+\z/,
      message: "should use only letters and numbers."
    },
    length: { within: 8..100 },
    uniqueness: {
      case_sensitive: false,
      if: :will_save_change_to_login?
    }

  validates :password,
    confirmation: { if: :require_password? },
    length: {
      minimum: 8,
      if: :require_password?
    }
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation
    length: {
      minimum: 8,
      if: :require_password?
  }
end
```

and just in case

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "home_page#index"
  get "/home", to: "home_page#index"

  resources :users do
    resource :user_profile
  end

  resource :user_session
end
```

i did think it was a bug so i updated the authlogic gem to **6.4.1** from **6.4.0**.  Needless to say it didn't help either.

and here is

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'authlogic'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem "scrypt", "~> 3.0"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

  gem 'capybara'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

#### new.html.erb (form)

```
<%= form_for @user_session, url: user_session_url do |f| %>
  <% if @user_session.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user_session.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @user_session.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :login %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :login %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :remember_me %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Login" %>
<% end %>
```

#### migration table

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Email
      t.string    :email
      t.index     :email, unique: true

      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Login
      t.string    :login

      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Password
      t.string    :crypted_password
      t.string    :password_salt

      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::PersistenceToken
      t.string    :persistence_token
      t.index     :persistence_token, unique: true

      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::SingleAccessToken
      t.string    :single_access_token
      t.index     :single_access_token, unique: true

      # Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::PerishableToken
      t.string    :perishable_token
      t.index     :perishable_token, unique: true

      # See "Magic Columns" in Authlogic::Session::Base
      t.integer   :login_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.integer   :failed_login_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime  :last_request_at
      t.datetime  :current_login_at
      t.datetime  :last_login_at
      t.string    :current_login_ip
      t.string    :last_login_ip

      # See "Magic States" in Authlogic::Session::Base
      t.boolean   :active, default: false
      t.boolean   :approved, default: false
      t.boolean   :confirmed, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the form? And what's the migration file?

Comment: Added. Please see if there is anything wrong there. Its been bugging for the past two weeks. So much so that I have decided to work on a different branch with a different authentication solution. just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Your account in not active error` that's because your migration file added `Magic States` fields:

```rb
# See "Magic States" in Authlogic::Session::Base
t.boolean   :active, default: false
t.boolean   :approved, default: false
t.boolean   :confirmed, default: false
```

That means you have to set those fields to `true` before you can log a user in.

So you could remove those fields in a new migration if you don't need them.

```rb
def change
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.remove :title, :active
    t.remove :title, :approved
    t.remove :title, :confirmed
  end
end
```

Comment: Documentation PRs welcome if you can think of any improvement to either the migration comment or readme. For example, the migration comment might say "optional".